# Ember error Modified attribute twice in a single render

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have a hbs template defined as below (simply iterates through an array 'myContainers' and prints some attrs):

```
{{#each containers as |rows|}}          
        {{/each}}
```

Also my component JS is as below (Iterates through 'items' prop & finally returns an array):

```
containers: function(){
    var self = this;        
    //Some logic to set array attribute values
    return this.get('myInfo').rows;
}.property('myInfo.items'),
```

Now my question is with the above code, everything works fine and I am able to see the data on screen.

But the moment, I try to update my hbs by wrapping in 'some-acc' component;

You modified 'someAttr' twice in a single render error and I cannot see any data.

PS: It is surely not an issue with the my-acc component as the same is tested in other places.

Comment: I often see this type of error when something else is the cause. Ignore the 'modified twice' error and look for a previous error or warning in the console that will give you a better clue.

Comment: Actually...it starts with this error...no other error...

Comment: Wondering if there is some issue of writing code...when using Ember.set inside computed properties...

Comment: @testndtv Using `set` in a computed property is considered bad practice and could cause issues like the one you are facing. A computed property should not have any side effects.